# Floating a form onto an image - sidebar

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I need to position this form into place on top of the image in sidebar of my blog posts page:

http://insightcxo.com/category/blog/

Right now the image and the form are in the same container but are below one another.

Comment: I would suggest creating a simplified version of your layout problem and putting it on jsFiddle or codepen, so that after you fix the problem others can still benefit from the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup has several issues in it. This is what I'm seeing in the provided link:

```
<td align="center" valign="top">
  <a href="http://insightcxo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/blog-form-background.png">
    <img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-1035" src="http://insightcxo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/blog-form-background.png" alt="blog form background" width="370" height="400">
  </a>
  <p></p>
  <table class="bodyContainer webFormBodyContainer" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <!-- form is in here -->
  </table>
</td>
```

First, you've got an `<a>` tag with an `<img>` in it, which has a height of 400px. So that's pushing your `<table>` (which includes your `<form>`) down.

What you want to do is only have that image as a background image, and not a background of an `<a>` tag. That way, you can nest your `<form>` inside the container with the background image.

Something along the lines of this:

```
<div style="background: url('http://insightcxo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/blog-form-background.png');">
  <form></form>
</div>
```

Although a few extra pointers:

1. Don't use `<table>` tags for layout purposes. Only use them for actual data tables.
2. Avoid inline styles (I've done that above just to show you where the background image style should go. Instead, set a class, like `.form-container`, and apply your styles in a separate CSS file.
3. Avoid having extra markup. What's that empty `<p>` tag doing there?

Comment: Hi benjarwar,

I tried your suggestion and it almost worked!

Can you check the link again? I just need to resize the image so that all the text can be seen.

Do i need to resize the div to do that?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually I figured it out!

Thanks for the help again.